# Firebase rules are giving PERMISSION DENIED on user trying to save favorited items

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is my Firestore directory structure:

```
items \ {document} \ 1 item with date, image etc
users \ {document} \ favoriteItems
```

On startup: the App downloads the list of items.

These are my old rules, which is obviously not correct for production:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But with the old rules, I don't get the error. So it must be in the rules.

When the user favorite's an item for the first time, the user is not existent yet in the `users` collection. The users subdirectory have the `document=**` wildcard:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /items/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }    
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

But these rules give below error:

> Firestore: (21.4.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/vsfcRpgewjNdFfQomf7MohcOMcA3/favoriteItems order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

That seems obvious because the first time the `document` does not exist yet. But also when it's present, I get the same error message. What are the proper rules for this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read from collection `users/vsfcRpgewjNdFfQomf7MohcOMcA3/favoriteItems`, but only have rules defined for `users/vsfcRpgewjNdFfQomf7MohcOMcA3`. Since you're not granting recursive access in those rules, access to nested collections is denied.

You'll want to either allow nested access with a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards):

```
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
}
```

Or alternatively, allow access to the specific subcollection:

```
match /users/{document} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
  match /favoriteItems/{favorite} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
  }
}
```

The latter is more useful if your rules for the nested collections are different from the permissions on the containing document.

Comment: It gives the same error for both rules set: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /items/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
   }
  }
}

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is one of the problems in your rules/code, but there might be more. Please edit your question to include the updated rules, and the minimal code with which you can trigger the problem. Be sure this code has no external dependencies, so it can run standalone. If there is any external dependency, log the value of that dependency and include the output of that logging in the question.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question. When using the old rules, everything works, so the problem seems to be in the rules I think..